# does sprintf delete the last null char it added last time it wrote to the buffer?

Tags: c, printf

```
x = 2; n = 0;

for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if(A[i] > 1)
    {
        n += sprintf(buf + n, "%d ", A[i]);
    }
}
```

> '2'[SPACE]'\0'
>   (deletes '\0' adds '3'[SPACE]'\0')
>   '2'[SPACE]'3'[SPACE]'\0'

Is this what happening during the loop?
Thanks.

Comment: I formatted your question.  **Please** don't post ugly code!

Comment: ugly for who? i prefer one liners                                 x=2;n=0;for(i=0;i<x;i++){if(A[i]>1){n+=sprintf(buf+n,"%d ",A[i]);}} if the compiler understands it, it is the opposite of ugly

Comment: Ugly for at least two people.

Comment: note: it wasn't one-liner when i posted it

Comment: @MikeL Not trying to insult you.  Just a suggestion.  Makes people want to actually read what you post if you include, for example, spaces.  Do this: `x = 1;`; not this: `x=1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told it to start writing at the character position that held the null byte at the end of the first loop, so being a well-behaved, obedient function, that's what it did. And doing so zapped the null byte that was there beforehand.

So yes, `sprintf()` does overwrite the last null character it wrote (because you told it to).

Another way of looking at it is the `sprintf()` returns the length of the string it wrote. On the first iteration, that's tantamount to `strlen(buf)`.  The value stored at `buf + strlen(buf)` is, by definition of 'the length of a string', the null byte that terminates the string.  So, on the second loop, you start writing at the end of the string.  The return value gives you the length of string added to `buf`, so the `n += <newlen>` operation gives you the extra length of the string, keeping the cycle going safely.

Theoretically, `sprintf()` might return a negative value.  I don't think that's material here, but if it did happen, you'd have problems because of decrementing instead of incrementing the counter (`n`).  Also, it might be safer to use `snprintf()`, but then you have to adjust the available length on each iteration, and worry about buffer overflows (but you had to worry about those anyway, but you did that by allocating enough, or more than enough, space in the first place).